# pgAdmin cannot connect to PostgreSQL 9.1

Tags: ubuntu, database, postgresql

I am trying to use pgAdmin on Windows to connect to `postgresql` 9.1.8 running on localhost's Ubuntu 12.04 VM. The host's port 5432 forwards to VM's port 5432.

**pgAdmin Error:**

`Error connecting to the server: could not receive data from server: Software caused connection abortion (0x00002745/10053)`

**postgresql.conf**

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONNECTIONS AND AUTHENTICATION
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432
```

**pg_hba.conf**

```
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

**netstat -nlp | 5432**

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29035/postgres
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     50823    29035/postgres      /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

**iptables rule**

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT
```

PostgreSQL service has been restarted and pgAdmin still gives the error. Any ideas what have caused it?

Comment: I made it such that `localhost:5432` on my Windows host machine forwards to `localhost:5432` on the Ubuntu VM provisioned by Vagrant/puppet. Port 80 forwarding works well, I can access `http://localhost` from my host system

Comment: Can you connect to the server if you try 'telnet localhost 5432'?

Comment: Port forwarding doesn't really help in your case. You probably need to do SNAT on your Linux machine but anyway it looks like a backwards solution. I think it is better to make pg listen on the eth interface. If you need security, you can always restrict access to it using your firewall.

Comment: I cant telnet to localhost:5432. I get the error `Connection closed by remote host` when telneting using Putty.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out ?

Comment: can you please post the screenshot about telnet?

Comment: Try to assign an internal ip in the vm and forward to that ip in vbox. Eg 192.168.10.10:5432

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and it boiled down to 3 steps:

1- On Mavericks (same for 10.6+) port 5432 is already taken so 
 needed this: --- config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5432, host: 5433'  on 'Vagrantfile' and then you use port 5433 to connect through pgadmin3

2- listen_address = '*' # in postgresql.conf, allows for the server to listen as a socket connection from all ip's

3- need to enable host in 'pg_hba.conf'

I put the provisioning shell script required for postgresql on vagrant here:

https://gist.github.com/haknick/7394776

Answer (score 0):

The TCP packets are allowed IN but are they allowed OUT from the VM to the host?

If an INPUT rule is needed, an OUTPUT rule is probably needed as well, such as:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 5432 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Also you may look at this related question:
[Unable to connect to Postgres on Vagrant Box - Connection refused](https://serverfault.com/questions/373984/unable-to-connect-to-postgres-on-vagrant-box-connection-refused)